# Carrierwave files not deleting from S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I'm using the `carrierwave` and `carrierwave-aws` gems to upload to S3 from a Rails application. I can upload files without any issue, but I can't remove them from S3.

My ActiveRecord model is called Episode and its video property is set by my `CarrierWave::Uploader::Base` uploader (which includes `CarrierWave::Video`).

Here are the steps I've followed:

1. Create an episode
2. Upload a video, verify it exists on S3 (this works!)
3. Call `episode.remove_video!; episode.save!` from the console
4. At this point, the video still exists on S3, despite receiving no error message

I've also tried:

```
episode.video.remove!
episode.save!
```

Which produces this output, but doesn't delete the file from S3:

```
[180] pry(main)> episode.video.remove!
=> [:remove_versions!]
```

I've also tried:

`episode.destroy!`

which should call the ActiveRecord callback [added by Carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#skipping-activerecord-callbacks), but doesn't. I added my own before_destroy method (`destroy_assets` below), but this also doesn't work.

Here is my setup:

carrierwave.rb

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.storage    = :aws
  config.aws_bucket = 'BUCKET_NAME'
  config.aws_acl    = 'public-read'

  config.aws_authenticated_url_expiration = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7

  config.aws_attributes = {
    expires: 2.week.from_now.httpdate,
    cache_control: 'max-age=604800'
  }

  config.aws_credentials = {
    access_key_id:     ENV['aws_access_key'],
    secret_access_key: ENV['aws_secret'],
    region:            'us-east-1'
  }

  config.remove_previously_stored_files_after_update = true

end
```

video_uploader.rb

```
class VideoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::Video
  storage :was

  def store_dir
    "uploads/videos/#{model.id}"
  end

end
```

episode.rb

```
class Episode < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :video, VideoUploader
  before_destroy :destroy_assets

  def destroy_assets
    self.video.remove! if self.video
    self.save!
  end

end
```

The AWS credentials I'm using are for an IAM user with the `AmazonS3FullAccess` policy, if that makes any difference here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would update your store_dir to be:

```
"uploads/videos/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
```

So that carrierwave, while utilizing the mounting system, removes the file, it knows where to find it when it calls the full name method internally!